# How to check UNIQUEIDENTIFIER value and replace with select string value if it exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2012 script and I need to do logic like this;

if ans.value is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER /Guid then select value(string) from xtable where xtable.value = ans.value else ans.value (ans.value will be either string or empty)

This is far I have achieved..

```
SELECT 
  ans.Id,
  calculatedVal = ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ans.Value), 'select from xtable....') ?????

FROM [Answers] AS ans
```

so basically I need to perform sql select and assign string value to 'calculatedVal' if TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ans.Value) IS NOT NULL... how can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
  ans.Id,
  CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ans.Value) IS NOT NULL THEN 
            (select TOP 1 col_name from xtable WHERE ... ORDER BY ...)
       ELSE ans.Value
  END AS calculatedVal
FROM [Answers] AS ans;
```

Or using IIF

```
SELECT 
  ans.Id,
  IIF(TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ans.Value) IS NOT NULL,
      (select TOP 1 col_name from xtable WHERE ... ORDER BY ...)
      ,ans.Value)AS calculatedVal
FROM [Answers] AS ans;
```